# Including header files from other directories

Tags: c, visual-studio, header-files

I am working on a rather large dll and I dont want to use the convectional `Source Files` and `Header Files` layout because it would take me a while to find the file I am looking for. Instead, I moved my main.c file out of Source Files and into the main directory that is housed within my solution (I am using Visual Studio 2019).

[image: Project Layout]

But I can't figure out how to include Base.h from within Main.c I tried doing `#include "base/Base.h"` but that gives me a red underline saying, "cannot open source file". Maybe there is something I have to edit in the properties of my solution, but I have tried for a while now without being able to get this to work.

Comment: Make sure your header include path includes your main source path, and that `base` is relative to that, not in some other location.

Comment: I can’t remember but I don’t think the file location in the solution explorer has to match the filesystem, the solution explorer is just an organisational view. Double check your filesystem for the paths, but your include statement should work if the filesystem was laid out as you expected.

Comment: You might be better off leaving main.c in the regular source files directory and moving everything else into subfolders of it. I suspect your IDE is configured to search for header files starting from the regular source directory, and that is why it does not find it from “base/Base.h”. Still, the compiler might, because it is typical for a compiler to use the directory of the current source file as a base for searching (possibly among others, in multiple searches). There might be a configuration setting to change that, but leaving main.c in its usual place might be the better approach.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think I see the issue I ended up moving Main.C and base into a new src folder. But when I go to the path my files are stored the Base files are not actually located inside the base directory and the src directory does not even exist what is going on here with visual Studio? Is there a way to edit VS so that it recognizes my file structure.

Comment: The general best practice is to never type out relative/absolute paths inside `#include`. Instead handle paths through your IDE/make file/build config. That way the compiler gets passed the relevant paths for each file at the point of launching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "folder" `base` is not a folder, it is a filter which can be used to sort your files for e.g. `.cpp` and `.h`. `Main.c`, `Base.c` and `Base.h` should all be in the same directory so you could just `#include "Base.h"` for it to work.

I would recommend to create an actual folder and switch to "Show All Files" (in the Solution Explorer in the top the button with like three rectangles above of each other). Then you can just create a new folder with: right clicking the project -> clicking on Add -> clicking on New Folder.

[image: change to "Show All Files"]

[image: create a new folder]

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing #include "base/Base.h" but that gives me a red underline saying, "cannot open source file".

if it compiles then that error doesnt matter and should go away. `gcc -o Main.c main`

Comment: `gcc -o Main.c main` is a very bad idea.

Comment: It does not compile it says it cannot open source file "base/Base.H